# Irreducible homogeneous ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, graded-rings

I have the following question:

> Let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal. Is it true that $I$ is irreducible if and only if it can't be written as the intersection of two homogeneous ideals?

So, is it sufficient checking the irreducibility on homogeneous ideals? If it's true, how can I prove this result?

Comment: What is the definition of an irreducible ideal ?

Comment: @Cantlog An ideal which is not the intersection of two proper ideals properly containing it.

Comment: @user26857 This question is too old for moderators to migrate - but you could always just ask it on MO (and link back to here so people don't get upset about cross-posting).

Comment: Asked now on MO, too: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162739/graded-irreducible-ideals-are-irreducible

Comment: A proof posted in here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162739/graded-irreducible-ideals-are-irreducible/216106#216106

See [here][1] for a related question.


  [1]: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215768/is-an-irreducible-ideal-in-r-also-irreducible-in-rx